# declaring input for Dictionaries in python

Tags: python

need help on the highlighted lines in the python code:

```
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split() <--- doubt
    scores = list(map(float, line)) <--- doubt
    student_marks[name] = scores

print (student_marks)
```

The output which i get is below:

```
2
abc 23 34 45
def 45 46 47
{'abc': [23.0, 34.0, 45.0], 'def': [45.0, 46.0, 47.0]}
```

Can you guys please help me explain the need for the marked line in the code. Couldn't quite get the concept.

Comment: Try to print them during execution

Answer (score 4):

```
name, *line = input().split() <--- doubt

input()  # reads single line of input
# 'abc 23 34 45'

.split()  # splits it into a list of whitespace separated tokens
# ['abc', '23', '34', '45']

name, *line = ...  # name is assigned first token, line a list of the remaining tokens
name  # 'abc'
line  #  ['23', '34', '45']

scores = list(map(float, line))  # maps float function onto the list of strings
scores  # [23.0, 34.0, 45.0]
```

Some references:

- [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
- [starred assignment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#id4)

Comment: why `line` needs to be unpacked before applying `map` function?

Comment: `name, line = ...` will only work if you have an iterable with exactly two elements on the right hand side. That's why you need to assign line a dynamic length list.

Comment: @raviraja `*line` isn't unpacking semantics here, rather it's more like arbitrary length assignment, meaning take the rest of the rvalues after the first, and assign it to a tuple called `line`.

Answer (score 1):

1)name, *line = input().split() <--- doubt

The * is being used to store the additional returns from the split statement.
Let's say you have:

name, *line = input().split()

print(name)

print(*line)

And you ran this code and say you entered: "abc 23 34 45", it will print out:

abc

[23, 34, 45]

2)scores = list(map(float, line)) <--- doubt

Here, the map() function returns a map object(which is an iterator) of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable (list, tuple, etc.).
For more understanding, refer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

->map() function maps float function onto the list of strings.

For example:
line = [23, 34, 45]
then scores = list(map(float, line)) will output to: scores = [23.0, 34.0, 45.0]

Answer (score 0):

The line `name, *line = input().split()` splits the input by white spaces, assigning the first item into `name`, and the rest of the items are assigned to `line` as a list, which, in the next line `scores = list(map(float, line))`, gets mapped to a list of floating numbers into `scores`.

Answer (score 0):

```
name, *line = "foo 23 34 45".split()
assert(name == "foo");
assert(line == ["23", "34", "45"])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

```
scores = list(map(float, line))
assert(scores == [23.0, 34.0, 45.0])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

*you want to get data form user we use*

```
scanf('%d %d', %name, %value)
name, value=input(), input()
```

*Another solution is that:*

```
name, value=input().split()
```

*use split method*